# ArcGIS Pro repeatedly opens in foreground while opening Pro-Doc

Tags: arcgis-pro

Does ArcGIS Pro have a setting that prevents it from repeatedly opening in the foreground? Unlike other programs that open once in the foreground and then stay in the background when another program is opened "on top" of it, it keeps popping back to the foreground while it is initiating/opening. This behavior interrupts side-tasks I am trying to accomplish, and is frustrating when compounded over the course of the day. Note: Once a ProDoc is fully loaded/initiated it will stay running in the background.

Comment: Posted same question on ESRI-Communities here: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcgis-pro-opens-in-foreground-repeatedly-while-opening-pro-doc/m-p/1066469#M41813